# Is it considered a lofty thing for a man to not look in a mirror (R' Akiva Eiger)?

Tags: halacha, rav-akiva-eiger

[He says](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.182.6?lang=he&with=Rabbi%20Akiva%20Eiger&lang2=he) that nowadays, men and women look in mirrors so there's no prohibition of "*lo yilbash*" for a man to look in a mirror, but he says that the "*chaveirim"* refrain from it. This is based on a gemara etc.

Is it *muskam*, who are *chaveirim* (Gilyon Maharsha says the same basically), what do they base this on? Is there really any *ma'alah* in not looking in a mirror for a man nowadays?

Comment: Did you check his references?

Comment: @DoubleAA not yet, I am mainly interested if anyone _after_ R' Eiger says anything

Comment: א) ר"ן (ע"ז דף ט: ד"ה שומט) – "ואילו בתוספתא תניא התירו לבית ר"ג לראות במראה מפני שהן זקוקין למלכות והכי איתא בירושלמי יש לומר דבכל מקום שרגילין האנשים להסתכל במראה כמו הנשים מותר וליכא משום לא ילבש גבר שמלת אשה ושמעתא דהכא ומתני' בשבת ותוספתא נמי בהכי איירי ואפ"ה הוצרכו להתיר לבית רבן גמליאל לפי שהחברים היו נמנעים בכ"מ"

Comment: Also, in case anyone didn't understand that the term habher refers to a scholarly/pious class of "colleagues":  https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%91%D7%A8_(%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94)

Comment: They say this is why Chassidim don't wear ties.

Comment: @MichoelR I feel Chassidim wouldn't look in a mirror even if there wasn't a gemara about looking in mirrors

Comment: ROY held that in our days even talmide hakhamim (the functional equivalent of "חברים") are permitted to look in the mirror - due to changes in societal expectations and the need to preserve the dignity of the rabbinate. Implying perhaps that not only ought they not hold back, but that it is proper to actively utilize a mirror. See שו"ת יחוה דעת הלק שישי סימן מ"ט דף קצה